# jquery on click enable disable selects + moving divs

Tags: jquery

I have some code that a gentleman was kind enough to work with me on.   He's done a fantastic job getting it functioning as it is.    But i've noticed one small issue that i can't solve.  Unfortunately the skill level for this is slightly beyond my capabilities. So any assistance would be appreciated.

A functioning demo of it is located at >> http://jsfiddle.net/5fM9p/

The problem is that when 'remove' is clicked, i need it to also reenable the selects that initially disabled upon adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your delete function like the below will do that for you.

```
$(".remove_from_cart").live("click", function(){
    var item=$(this);
    var itemId=item.parent().find(".product").attr("id");   
    item.parent().remove();
    var disabled=$(".added").find("#"+itemId).parent();   
    disabled.find("select").removeAttr("disabled");
    disabled.find("p").remove();
    disabled.append('<a class="add_to_cart" href="#add">Add To Cart</a>');   

});
```

**But i see a problem with your HTML markup.** You have more than one element with the same ID. That is not good. **ID's should be unique**.  You should probably fix that.

Another thing is that once you re-enable the link Add to Cart ( When the remove the cart is clicked), It wont work because you binded it earlier. So you need to change your binding code to use `live` method like this

```
$(".add_to_cart").live("click",function (e) { 
   //Your remaining code goes here
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/5fM9p/23/

Comment: +1, `You have more than one element with the same ID`, its better to use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".remove_from_cart").live("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().find("select").attr("id");
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#" + id).parent().find("select").attr("disabled", "");
    $("#" + id).parent().find("p").remove();
    $("#" + id).parent().append('<a class="add_to_cart" href="#add">Add To Cart</a>'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fM9p/25/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6V52G/

Use attributes that can be used to identify which groups of elements belong to which product and remove the whole setupForm function, put those in HTML from the get-go.